# Node js AWS Lambda using mysql connecting to RDS - Error: Handshake inactivity timeout

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an AWS Lambda function running a node application using `mysql` that always fails to connect to the RDS instance with the following error: `Error: Handshake inactivity timeout`.

Minor detail that should be irrelevant: the application is a Nest application using TypeORM. However, I also included a test function in the application startup that performs a raw connection and query using the `mysql` package directly that does succeed when connecting to the instance while running the application on my local machine. I have double checked that the environment variables in the Lambda function are set correctly.

I have ensured many times that I have the following security group rules (inbound on the security group containing the RDS instance and outbound on the security group containing the Lambda function) with the proper source/destination:

- The correct source/destination security group (RDS sg in the Lambda's sg, Lambda's sg in the RDS sg)
- The CIDR of my VPC (everything is under the same VPC)
- The CIDR of each subnet used by the RDS and the Lambda function (one rule per CIDR) (I even put the Lambda function in the same subnets as the RDS instance)

I have tried both All Traffic and just TPC for port 3306 on the above rules.

I have exhausted Google to find the above rules to try. I found in several answers that the rules with the source/destination security groups should do the trick, but I tried the others just to see if they would work. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable. The cause was actually a Nest error about a missing package that was causing the application to crash. I just saw the database errors in CloudWatch and assumed that the application was bootstrapping properly but the database connection was bombing out. I guess the connection bombs because the application bombs. I find it strange that the connection attempt continues after the application crashes, though...

In any case, the solution was to add the missing package to the `forceInclude` list in `serverless.yml`. So for anybody else having this issue and you have checked your environment variables and security group rules and all that, check the logs for other issues that may cause the application to crash.